# list-style-type, how to Invert from lower-alpha and decimal on nested items in an ol?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to invert the list-style-type in an OL nested items, sub-items, sub-sub-items, etc. I'm using css counters but is not working, what I'm doing wrong?

```
ol{
    counter-reset: item
}

ol li{
    display: block;
    margin-left:5px;
}

ol[style*="list-style-type: lower-alpha;"] li:before{
    content: counters(item, ".", lower-alpha) ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ol[style*="list-style-type: lower-alpha;"] li ol li:before{
    content: counters(item, ".", decimal) ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

What I need to achieve is this:

[image]

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/un8a4m7w/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a counter for each layer separately

```css
ol{
    counter-reset: primary;
}
ol ol{
    counter-reset: secondary;
}
ol ol ol{
    counter-reset: tertiary;
}
ol li{
    display: block;
  margin-left:5px;
}

ol.list-root li:before{
    content: counters(primary, ".", upper-alpha) ". ";
    counter-increment: primary;
}

ol.list-root li ol li:before{
    content: counters(primary, ".", upper-alpha) "." counters(secondary, ".", decimal) ". " ;
    counter-increment: secondary;
}
ol.list-root li ol li ol li:before{
    content: counters(primary, ".", upper-alpha) "-" counters(secondary, ".", decimal) "-" counters(tertiary, ".", upper-alpha) ". " ;
    counter-increment: tertiary;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list-root">
    <li>item A</li>
    <li>item B</li>
    <li>item C
        <ol>
            <li>sub-item</li>
            <li>sub-item</li>
            <li>sub-item</li>
            <li>sub-item
                <ol>
                    <li>sub-sub-item</li>
                    <li>sub-sub-item</li>
                    <li>sub-sub-item</li>
                    <li>sub-sub-item</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Your approaching is exactly what I was trying to do and not getting, thank you Swimmer F!